# Xpath, choosing a fallback node

Tags: xpath

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<container>
  <type>01</type>
  <text>one</text>
</container>
<container>
  <type>02</type>
  <text>two</text>
</container>
```

**EDIT** the order of the `container`s isn't fixed.

I'm using xPath (through ruby's nokogiri) to choose text from this document. I want to be able to take the `text` in the `container` with a `type` of 02, but take the `text` from the `container` with a `type` of 01 if that doesn't exist.

I can do

```
/container/type[text() = "02" or text() = "01"]/parent::container
```

Which will get me both elements, then I can use some ruby to sort and take the right one (as this would return the 01 element first), but this feels clumsy.

I've search stackoverflow and there's nothing immediately apparent which allows me to sort element output with simple xpath, but is there a way to command xpath to take an element, but fallback to another if it doesn't exist?

Cheers!

Comment: While a pure xpath solution may be available and cleaner, an alternative is to try 02 alone first and then check for 01 alone . Of course this may look as messy as current

Comment: It's what I'm going with at the moment, the only reason I'm looking for this solution is I think it's more likely that the "02" record won't exist, and I'm operating under the assumption that any pure xpath solution would be faster than doing two xpath queries from ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're going to like it, but it does what you want:

```
concat(substring(//container[type/text() = '02']/text,1,string-length(//container[type/text()='02'])*boolean(//container[type/text()='02']/text())),substring(//container[type/text() = '01']/text,1,string-length(//container[type/text()='01'])*number(boolean(//container[type/text()='01']/text())and not(boolean(//container[type/text()='02']/text())))))
```

I'll break it down in a sec...

---

OK, so this part:

concat(

```
substring(//container[type/text() = '02']/text,1,string-length(//container[type/text()='02'])*boolean(//container[type/text()='02']/text())),
```

Grabs the `<text>` from type=2 if it exists.

This part:

```
substring(//container[type/text() = '01']/text,1,string-length(//container[type/text()='01'])
```

Grabs the `<text>` from type=1, and only returns it if type=2 doesn't exist using this:

```
*number(boolean(//container[type/text()='01']/text())and not(boolean(//container[type/text()='02']/text())))))
```

Hope that helps clear it up, I know you were looking for something clean, but for what you wanted using XPath, it's a little messy.

Comment: Thanks! It does indeed do what I need - but as you say, it's at a level of complexity which probably obfuscates what I'm trying to do - I'll check to see what's faster, but it'd have to be a lot quicker to warrant this level of complexity.

Comment: Np, I'd be interested in your results for that

Answer (score 0):

If the order is fixed, you can select both and then take the last one. It will be 02, if there is only 02, and 02, if there is an 01 before it in the document...

```
 (/container/type[text() = "02" or text() = "01"]/parent::container)[last()]
```

Or shorter, since the value of a node is its text and a comparison just looks for a matching pair:

```
 (/container[type = ("01", "02")])[last()]
```

(at least that works in XPath 2, not sure if it is the same in XPath 1)

-

edit:

Actually it is pretty easy. You can check with `//container[type = "02"]`, if there is a container with type 02, so you can take all 02 containers and all 01 containers, if there are not type 02 containers, leading to:

```
 //container[type = "02" or (type = "01" and not(//container[type = "02"]))]
```

it'S quite slow through

Comment: I can't assume the order is fixed :( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
(//container/type[.='02'], //container/type[.='01'])[1]/..
```

The outer brackets construct a sequence from the type element with text value `02`, followed by the type with text value `01`. The `,` operator omits any undefined values, so if one is missing, the sequence consists only of the other, and if both are missing, it's an empty sequence.

`[1]` selects the first item from that sequence

`/..` is abbreviated syntax for `parent::node()`, which is equivalent to your `parent::container` in this case.

You might expect this to work:

```
//container/(type[.='02'],type[.='01'])[1]/..
```

but (in Saxon at least) this gives you *both* containers ; or this:

```
(//container/(type[.='02'],type[.='01']))[1]/..
```

but this gives you the `01` container, because the result of the brackets is both nodes in *document order*.